# Separating the last number in each line from the letters

Tags: awk, sed, separator

I have a long file with provisional SNP IDs and alleles, which looks like this:

```
14_611646T,C
14_881226CT,C
14_861416.1GGC,GGCGCGCGCG
```

I would like to separate the last number in each line from the letters (separate SNP ID from alleles). So to look like this:

```
14_611646 T,C
14_881226 CT,C
14_861416.1 GGC,GGCGCGCGCG
```

I tried both `awk` and `sed`, however, underscore keeps making the problem. For example:

```
sed 's/^[0-9][0-9]*/& / File1 > File2
```

gave me

```
14 _611646T,C
14 _881226CT,C
14 _861416.1GGC,GGCGCGCGCGC
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to understand what is the most smart way to achieve this.

It's better to avoid using a regex that match all the line, instead try to find the portion that need change.

##### Using `sed` with `-E` aka `E`xtented `R`egex `E`xpression :

```
sed -E 's/^[0-9_.]+/& /' file
```

##### Yields:

```
14_611646 T,C
14_881226 CT,C
14_861416.1 GGC,GGCGCGCGCG
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | the beginning of the string anchor |
| `[0-9_.]+` | any character of: '0' to '9', '_', '.' (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

In the right part of `sed`'s substitution, `&` is what matched in the left part.

##### Bonus

```
sed 's/[[:upper:]]/ &/' file
```

`[[:upper:]]` is a `POSIX` regex class meant for *all upper case letters*.

Answer (score 2):

Using any sed to add a blank after the last digit:

```
$ sed 's/.*[0-9]/& /' file
14_611646 T,C
14_881226 CT,C
14_861416.1 GGC,GGCGCGCGCG
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed 's/[[:alpha:]]/ &/'` to insert a space before the first letter:

```
14_611646 T,C
14_881226 CT,C
14_861416.1 GGC,GGCGCGCGCG
```

Answer (score 1):

To insert a space between the last digit on a line and the next non-digit char, you can use `sed` like this:

```bash
sed 's/\(.*[0-9]\)\([^0-9]\)/\1 \2/' file # BRE 
sed -E 's/(.*[0-9])([^0-9])/\1 \2/'  file # ERE
```

*Details*:

- `\(.*[0-9]\)` (BRE) / `(.*[0-9])` (ERE) - Group 1 (`\1` in the replacement pattern refers to the value captured into this group): any text and then a digit (last occurrence on a line)
- `\([^0-9]\)` (BRE) / `([^0-9])` (ERE) - Group 2 (`\2` in the replacement pattern refers to the value captured into this group): a non-digit char.

See the [Bash demo online](https://ideone.com/9wBDor):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='14_611646T,C
14_881226CT,C
14_861416.1GGC,GGCGCGCGCG'

sed 's/\(.*[0-9]\)\([^0-9]\)/\1 \2/' <<< "$s"
sed -E 's/(.*[0-9])([^0-9])/\1 \2/' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
14_611646 T,C
14_881226 CT,C
14_861416.1 GGC,GGCGCGCGCG
```

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
14_611646T,C
14_881226CT,C
14_861416.1GGC,GGCGCGCGCG
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[0-9_.]*|[ACGT,]*"}{$1=$1;print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
14_611646 T,C
14_881226 CT,C
14_861416.1 GGC,GGCGCGCGCG
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field consist of either zero-or-more digits,underscore,dot or `ACGT`,comma, then I use `$1=$1` to trigger string rebuild and then `print` said line.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^([^[:alpha:],]*[[:digit:])([[:alpha:]])/\1 \2/' file
```

A pedantic solution.

N.B. This solution assumes that fields are separated by commas.